# ExtJS tooltip when there is an ellipsis in the column header

Tags: extjs, header, grid, tooltip, ellipsis

I need to make a tooltip appear in the column header with ellipsis.
Method isOverflow, dont work,because my header el.scrollWidth = el.offsetWidth

```
isOverflow: function (el) {
        return el.scrollWidth > el.offsetWidth;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally do this on column resize:

```
listeners:{
    columnResize: {
        fn: function (ct, column, width, eOpts){   
                 //check overflow
                 if (column.textEl.dom.offsetWidth<column.textInnerEl.dom.offsetWidth-5){
                     var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                                    target: column.titleEl.dom,
                                    html: column.text,
                                    autoDestroy: true
                               });
                      column.tooltip = tip;

                 } else {
                      //Remove when title visible
                      if (column.tooltip!=null)
                             column.tooltip.destroy();
                            
                 }
             }
        }
   }
```